# Content Security Policy: Ignoring report-sample within script-src: strict-dynamic specified

Tags: javascript, php, security, firefox, header

`Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'report-sample'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified`

Why do I get this error if I use

```
<?php

header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning on reactjs. It has been answered here on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/fpptyj/firefox_content_security_policy_console_output/).

TLDR: Can be ignored.